# Guessing at Battleship program

Tags: java

I'm having some problems with a battleship solution I'm creating using Java. A random set of ships are loaded onto a 10x10 board. 1 2hit ships 2 3hit ships 1 4hit ship and 1 5hit ship (total of 17 hits goal)

I made a nested loop to basically fire at every cell coordinate until I either used 100 shots or destroyed all the ships. The GOAL is to find a way to sink all the ships with 50 or less shots. My problem is I can't tell where the ships are in accordance to their sink location (as it only tells me if I sunk a ship, not if I hit) Also, it doesn't tell me what kind of ship I've sunk, but I can figure that out a lot easier if I know how to solve the hit issue.

So how can I deduct if I've "hit" a ship? the only "hit" i can confirm on my board is the final shot triggered by the "a ship has sunk" message.

Edit: Sorry, I should also mention I do not have access to the battleship class, I only have a class I make that will be used to solve this problem. I was given some methods of the class such as:

" public BattleShip() - you need to call the constructor once in your program to create an instance of the battleship game.

public boolean shoot(Point shot) - you need to call this function to make each shot. See the sample source code for an example use.

public int numberOfShipsSunk() - returns the total number of ships sunk at any point during the game. It is a good idea to use this method to determine when a ship has been sunk.

public boolean allSunk() - returns a boolean value that indicates whether all the ships have been sunk.

public int totalShotsTaken() - returns the total number of shots taken. Your code needs to be responsible for ensuring the same shot is not taken more than once.

public ArrayList shipSizes() - returns an ArrayList of all of the ship sizes. The length of the array indicates how many ships are present.

public enum CellState - this enum object is very useful for marking cells has either Empty, Hit or Miss. It also has a convenience toString method so that can be used for printing purposes. You may also create your own Enum / Class for this in your code, but it is suggested that you use this instead of integers / characters to mark a Cell state"

The CellState property doesn't actually exist/is private so i can't use that. This is my loop.

```
  x  = 0;
           for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           {
               y = 0;
             for(int j = 0; j < 10;j++) 
             {
                 if(x <=9 && y <=9) //X and Y  are less than or equal to 9...
             {
                     Point shot = new Point(x, y);

            // At the end of each decision on where to fire next you need to shoot

            if(shotTracker[x][y] == '-') // if space is free...
            {  battleShip.shoot(shot);
                if (sunkShip != battleShip.numberOfShipsSunk())
                {
                  shotTracker[x][y] = 'O'; //The hit that sunk the ship 
                  sunkShip++;
                }
                else
                shotTracker[x][y] = '*'; // set space to fired miss
            }
                 }



            gameShots = battleShip.totalShotsTaken();
            System.out.printf("You've shot %d times. The last shot's location was (%d,%d). You've hit something (not sure) times. You've sunk %d ships.\n", gameShots, x, y, battleShip.numberOfShipsSunk() );
            if(battleShip.allSunk() || gameShots >= shotLimit)
            {
                break;
            }
            y+=3;
             }
             if(battleShip.allSunk() || gameShots >= shotLimit)
            {
                break;
            }
             x++;
           } 
            if( gameShots >= shotLimit)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

And the output:

```
* - - * - - * - - * 
* - - * - - * - - * 
* - - * - - * - - * 
* - - * - - * - - * 
* - - * - - * - - * 
* - - O - - * - - * 
* - - * - - * - - * 
* - - * - - * - - * 
* - - * - - * - - *
```

This is a random output. I took a shot every 3 cells, and as you can see I sunk a ship but the O only tells me that was the finishing hit, so that was a vertical ship of unknown size on a random game...

Comment: What is a ship? Is it an own class? Then why not check if all its part are hit? Then give a result as sunk. Otherwise it is just a hit. Easy. Share your code so far...

Comment: `the only "hit" i can confirm on my board is the final shot triggered by the "a ship has sunk" message.` If that is all you know, you won't be able to check anything else unless you modify the code. If this is an option, fix the code to tell you have made a hit.

Comment: Looks like you need to use that enum class.

Comment: after countless tests, I cannot solve it as it is, I tried using battleship.CellState but it doesn't work. It also doesn't show up in the .dropdown box of useable methods and variables or has a getter. So I'm sort of stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My shot command

```
battleShip.shoot(shot)
```

evaluates to true or false, or hit or miss. When i check if true use "O" else use "*" O's pop up, so I guess I can do more work now. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever code you are using to determine if a ship has been sunk should be able to tell you if a ship is hit. Otherwise, how does it aggregate to know its sunk?

Comment: I'd tell you the answer would benefit from having more info, but then so would the question.

Comment: Yeah we need more info. Put your code on github or something op.

Comment: I'd prefer NOT github, simply for completeness of the question having its own code

Comment: Github is awesome, and would be great to assist him for this question as it is so broad.

Comment: Sure. But, the code should also go in the post to make the question a complete standalone question